# In CSS background-image with radial-gradient of dotted circle, is it possible to hide the dots at the edges?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this dotted pattern using CSS for the background of my HTML body.

Is it possible to hide the dots using CSS only which are at the edges only or make them transparent? The ones which are marked in red:

[image]

```
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, rgb(70, 70, 70) 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kzojwft1/

One workaround I can think of is to use a `::before` on the body with an absolute position and margin equal to the distance between dots and set the background on that. Just wondering if it's possible without doing that.

Here's my current workaround:

https://jsfiddle.net/kzojwft1/

```
:root{
  --dot-distance: 25px;
}

body::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--dot-distance);
    left: var(--dot-distance);
    right: var(--dot-distance);
    bottom: var(--dot-distance);
    background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, rgb(70, 70, 70) 1px, transparent 0);
    background-size: var(--dot-distance) var(--dot-distance);
}
```

Comment: No, I don’t think this is possible. There is little difference between this, and a “normal” repeated background image. And from the latter, you could also not just “cut out” a specific portion, it applies over the whole element area, same as your gradient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this out? I have added a box shadow around the body. So no matter what the viewport width is, the dots won't look as if it has touched the edge of the body.

```
  body {
     background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, rgb(70, 70, 70) 1px, transparent 0);
     background-size: 25px 25px;
     box-shadow: inset -2px 0px 0px 15px rgb(255 255 255);
     height: 100vh;
     margin:0;
  }
```

Comment: This is quite a clever idea and seems to require the least amount of changes to my original code. Thanks.

Comment: I made a small change to yours as I only wanted to hide them if the dot was touching the edge but not if they were close but not touching. So I changed it all to 0px and the border width to 2px (twice radius of dot): `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px var(--bg);`

Comment: @PranoyC. Yeah I expected some changes to be made there to make it look more cleaner. Glad It worked any ways!!

Answer (score 1):

We could use a white border and make the body `height: 100%`

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, rgb(70, 70, 70) 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 25px 25px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhak687z/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple background like below:

```css
html {
  --dot-distance: 25px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) top /100% 2px no-repeat, /* a line on the top*/
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) left/2px 100% no-repeat, /* a line on the left */
    radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, rgb(70, 70, 70) 1px, transparent 0) 0 0/var(--dot-distance) var(--dot-distance) space; /* use "space" as a background-repeat */
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Also like below:

```css
html {
  --dot-distance: 25px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) bottom/100% var(--dot-distance) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) right /var(--dot-distance) 100% no-repeat,
    radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, rgb(70, 70, 70) 1px, transparent 0) -2px -2px/var(--dot-distance) var(--dot-distance) round;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the top and left part with `background-position: 20px 20px`

```css
body {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, rgb(70, 70, 70) 1px, transparent 0);
  background-position: 20px 20px;
  background-size: 25px 25px;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhak687z/1/)